# Is there a better way to do multiple replace on a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `varchar` column which has a variation of the following string:

`Stations, FlightName, FlightWeeks, BindTo, SpotLength, foo, bar, etc...`

I need to change it to `Stations` to `Station`, `FlightName` to `Flight Name`, `BindTo` to `Bind To` etc to eventually come out like this:

`Station; Flight Name; Weeks; Bind To; Spot Length; foo; bar` etc

I have a really ugly code to do this:

```
 select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(GroupFlightsBy, ', ', ';'), 
'Stations', 'Station'), 'FlightName', 'Flight Name'), 'FlightWeeks', 'Weeks'), 'BindTo', 'Bind To'), 
'SpotLength', 'Spot Length')
```

Is there a better way of doing this, yet as performant?

Comment: First thought is not about the string replaces; but it sounds like you're merged data in a varchar-column instead of using separate columns. What does these values mean?

Comment: @SimonSvensson Basically those are values from the multi-select dropdown box.  The data is already there - I can't change it.

Comment: Why can't you change the database? Is it stored on some read-only media? Or are you saying that you, as a developer and assumed to know best during development, don't have the permissions to do changes? (Leading question; a database can always be changed; the no-change requirement is usually imposed from somewhere human-ish.)

Comment: @AngryHacker so you are going to deal with fixed number of data (like Stations, FlightName etc), right?

Comment: @SelvaTS Yes, fixed data.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Because this system is in maintenance mode.  I don't think I want to risk re-architecting the system just so that my code looks a bit prettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating CLR function is a solution for calling multiple REPLACE functions by replacing a single function. Yes there are some performance considerations using CLR functions but if you are dealing with low number of data, then it would be fine.

For creating CLR functions,

- [Enabling CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048.aspx)
- [Creating CLR project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Creating a sample CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=VS.90).aspx)

For your requirement I have created a sample function like this,

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString ReplaceFunc(string inputString)
    {
        return new SqlString (inputString
            .Replace("Stations", "Station")
            .Replace("FlightName", "Flight Name")
            .Replace("FlightWeeks", "Weeks")
            .Replace("BindTo", "Bind To")
            .Replace("SpotLength", "Spot Length")
            .Replace(", ", ";"));
    }
};
```

and called from SQL like this,

```
DECLARE @GroupFlightsBy VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Stations, FlightName, FlightWeeks, BindTo, 
SpotLength, foo, bar'

SELECT dbo.ReplaceFunc(@GroupFlightsBy)
```

For more about CLR functions,

http://sqlmag.com/database-development/common-language-runtime-dba-point-view﻿

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876797/311255

Comment: sure you can do it via clr. but a multireplace can also be done by a tsql-function, which would be easier to maintain and faster in execution. so why is this the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own Transformation-Function in TSQL but i think it will not be as performant as a multi-replace.
You should avoid using your multi-replace in WHERE/ORDER-clauses

Answer (score 0):

I like CLR idea.
Also the requirement is not very systematic.like FlightWeeks become Weeks.Why ?

Try my script,it work fine except FlightWeeks

```
DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(100)='FlightName'

Declare @Pattern1 as varchar(50)
Declare @Pattern2 as varchar(50)='%s%'
Declare @flg bit=0
  Set @Pattern1 = '%[^ ][A-Z]%'

   While PatIndex(@Pattern1 collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) > 0
BEGIN
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@Pattern1 collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) + 1, 0, ' ')

       set @flg=1
END
    if(@flg=0)
    if   PatIndex('%s%' , substring(@Temp,len(@temp),1)) >0
         Set @Temp = substring(@Temp,0,len(@temp))

select @Temp

--'FlightName' return Flight Name
--Stations return Station
-- foo return foo
--FlightWeeks return Flight Weeks
```